# Angular ng-option filter return all except

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list of countries coming from an external plugin, here is a small excerpt:

```
angular.module('maha.countries').config(['CountriesProvider',
    function(CountriesProvider) {
        CountriesProvider.setCountriesList({
            "AF": "Afghanistan",
            "AX": "Alandinseln",
            "AL": "Albanien",
            "DZ": "Algerien",
            "UM": "Amerikanisch-Ozeanien",
            "AS": "Amerikanisch-Samoa",
        });
    }])
})
```

And I have a select wit the countries

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-options="country[0] as country[1] for country in countries"
        id="country" name="country">
    <option translate>
        please_choose
    </option>
</select>
```

Now I want to show in the select, all countries except for Algeria for Example, how can I do that?

I tried using `filter:country='DZ'` but this shows only the Algeria, however, I need to show all of them but not Algeria.

Comment: Pure guess work, try `filter:{ country: '!DZ'}`

Comment: @HastaTamang doesn't work like that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `country[0]` is the two-letter country code, use:

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-options="country[0] as country[1] for country in countries 
                     | filter : {'0': '!DZ'} "
        id="country" name="country">
    <option translate>
        please_choose
    </option>
</select>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `filter` Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)